# Gitlab - How to write RTL in gitlab's wiki

Tags: gitlab

My native language is Right to Left so I wonder How can I write gitlab wiki from right to left instead of left to right? Is there any way to change the direction?

Comment: You can use `p`, `div` or `span` tag with `dir=rtl`, that does not make it to appear rtl but fixes mixed rtl/ltr text issue. (e.g `<p dir="rtl">متن rtl و ltr</p>`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `&rlm;` at the beginning of your text and `&lrm;` at the end; like:

```
&rlm;
این یک متن یا Text مهم است. امکان نوشتن Markdown در آن فراهم است
** مثال **
یک Markdown ساده
&lrm;
```

Answer (score 3):

From suggestions on this [github issue](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/147) you can use:

```
<p dir="rtl" align="right">متن rtl و ltr</p>
```

Or

```
<p dir=rtl align=right><span dir=ltr>@someone</span> متن rtl و ltr</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved for me by using

```
<div dir="rtl" markdown="1">
</div>
```

but unfortunately markdown does not work.
it is suggested by this [guy](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/147#issuecomment-538740019).